# Merging two select statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to merge 2 select results, one is like this:

```
SELECT count(emaildata2.EM_SENT_FLAG), emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK 
FROM `email-redeye`.emaildata2
WHERE emaildata2.EM_SENT_FLAG='Yes'
GROUP BY emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK
```

and the other like this:

```
SELECT count(emaildata2.EM_OPEN_FLAG), emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK 
FROM `email-redeye`.emaildata2
WHERE emaildata2.EM_OPEN_FLAG='Yes'
GROUP BY emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK
```

so that the output looks like this:

```
count(opens)|count(sends)|Week
 2               8        52
 5              15        53
```

I have tried various selects, unions but the results of the count always rolls up to a total and is not broken down by the week.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SUM WITH CASE** as below:

**Syntax** :

`CASE WHEN CONDITION 
    THEN TRUE_VALUE 
    ELSE FALSE_VALUE 
 END`

```
SELECT 
 SUM(CASE WHEN emaildata2.EM_SENT_FLAG = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) SEND_COUNT,
 SUM(CASE WHEN emaildata2.EM_OPEN_FLAG= 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OPEN_COUNT,
 emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK
FROM `email-redeye`.emaildata2
GROUP BY emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK
```

You can also use **SUM WITH IF** as below:

**Syntax** :

`IF(CONDITION) , TRUE_VALUE , FALSE_VALUE`

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(emaildata2.EM_SENT_FLAG='Yes', 1, 0) SEND_COUNT, 
  SUM(IF(emaildata2.EM_OPEN_FLAG='Yes', 1, 0)) OPEN_COUNT,
  emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK 
FROM `email-redeye`.emaildata2
GROUP BY emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the extra count but use IF and SUM:-

```
SELECT SUM(IF(emaildata2.EM_SENT_FLAG='Yes', 1, 0), SUM(IF(emaildata2.EM_OPEN_FLAG, 1, 0)), emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK 
FROM `email-redeye`.emaildata2
GROUP BY emaildata2.EMAIL_FINANCIAL_WEEK
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this from my phone, so it's a very short answer.

Make your second query a sub query of your first.

If you're not familiar with sub queries, it's basically a whole query in place of a table name. They are very useful.